# WP7 app is craching during a startup, sometimes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, crash

The most interesting thing is that it works fine with debugger and sometimes crashes when running without it. I'm testing app on Lumia 800.

Actually, i managed to "catch" a crash with a debugger, but it didn't provide me any useful info: app output just stopped at the line

```
'TaskHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'
```

and that's it. No exceptions and no sign of error.

I re-checked app.xaml.cs, but everything is ok there.

Did any of you already faced this strange behavior of Lumia 800?

EDIT1: unfortunately, replacing App.xaml.cs didnt help. It still stops loading at the Serialization.dll. Looking like its a 3rd party lib stops the party: i had removed Serialization.dll reference from the project.

Comment: "Sometimes crashes" is not a workable problem description. Lots of apps "crash sometimes". Could be threading issues, could be invalid templates or styles, anything. More code is needed.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt I'm also stuned, but i dont have any additional info. It exactly just stops loading. It works fine on 920 and 520, but some crap happens at 800 - maybe someone else faced it before? For now, i'm comparing App.xaml.cs with a template project, searching differences.

Comment: Can you show which code gets executed on-load? No way to figure out what is going wrong if we don't know what is happening...

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt Just to add: if there would be a templates issue, app would crash every time. However, in my case, it crashes just sometimes.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko: That would depend on whether the template/style gets parsed and/or used. Maybe there's a code path in release mode that uses one that's not present during debugging, no way to know for us, since there's still a distinct lack of actual code in the question.